# Jackson parse json has nest object is a JSON Stringify string

Tags: performance, scala, jackson

I have json data like this. I want to parse nest object of bidRequestString, bidResponseCreative, bidResponseData.

Here is json.

```
{
  "auctionId": "6c676664666b6621dr46c6b6c6c6a68",
  "bidRequestString": "{\"id\":\"6c676664666b6621dr46c6b6c6c6a68\",\"timestamp\":\"2015-09-04T04:44:24.381Z\",\"isTest\":false,\"url\":\"http://www.bsd.vvv.com/\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2pre) Gecko/20070118 Firefox/2.0.0.2pre\",\"protocolVersion\":\"Google Protocol Buffer\",\"exchange\":\"adx\",\"provider\":\"Google\",\"location\":{\"dma\":-1,\"metro\":-1,\"timezoneOffsetMinutes\":-1},\"segments\":{\"AdxDetectedVerticals\":[\"24:0.618452\",\"355:0.733486\",\"380:0.258120\",\"433:0.897398\",\"474:0.426707\"]},\"userIds\":{\"prov\":\"aGtqaq2ikdta21kZ2ZpbGZu70mo\",\"xchg\":\"aGtqaq2ikdta21kZ2ZpbGZu70mo\"},\"imp\":[{\"id\":\"66\",\"banner\":{\"w\":[220,300],\"h\":[600,450],\"id\":\"66\",\"pos\":0,\"topframe\":0},\"pmp\":{\"ext\":{\"adgroup_id\":\"17490739393\"}},\"formats\":[\"220x600\",\"300x450\"],\"position\":0},{\"id\":\"165\",\"banner\":{\"w\":120,\"h\":600,\"id\":\"165\",\"pos\":0,\"topframe\":0},\"pmp\":{\"ext\":{\"adgroup_id\":\"17490739393\"}},\"formats\":[\"120x600\"],\"position\":0}],\"spots\":[{\"id\":\"66\",\"banner\":{\"w\":[220,300],\"h\":[600,450],\"id\":\"66\",\"pos\":0,\"topframe\":0},\"pmp\":{\"ext\":{\"adgroup_id\":\"17490739393\"}},\"formats\":[\"220x600\",\"300x450\"],\"position\":0},{\"id\":\"165\",\"banner\":{\"w\":120,\"h\":600,\"id\":\"165\",\"pos\":0,\"topframe\":0},\"pmp\":{\"ext\":{\"adgroup_id\":\"17490739393\"}},\"formats\":[\"120x600\"],\"position\":0}],\"site\":{\"page\":\"http://www.bsd.vvv.com/\"},\"device\":{\"ua\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2pre) Gecko/20070118 Firefox/2.0.0.2pre\",\"ip\":\"106.100.108.0\",\"geo\":{\"zip\":\" 3000\"},\"language\":\"en\",\"ext\":{\"geo_criteria_id\":1000567}},\"user\":{\"id\":\"aGtqaq2ikdta21kZ2ZpbGZu70mo\",\"ext\":{\"cookie_age_seconds\":1595306}}}",
  "bidResponseCreative": "{\"itemId\":\"vkixi_cds0803_2015073133198\",\"campaignId\":\"859834ead1264843434cf6627ds43294d1\",\"htmlSnippet\":\"\\u003ciframe frameborder=0 scrolling=no width=\\\"300\\\" height=\\\"250\\\" src=\\\"//sv.xxx.com/adedge/api/bd/serving/simple/frame?aukey=1976ae04bc8eddsddsds34b02ae545333c\\u0026_=%%CACHEBUSTER%%\\u0026winning_price=%%WINNING_PRICE%%\\u0026google_click_url=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%\\u0026encrypt_value=%%ENCRYPT_VALUE%%\\\"\\u003e\\u003c/iframe\\u003e\",\"name\":\"Expandable Web\",\"formatCode\":\"billboard\",\"bd\":\"\",\"status\":1,\"deleted\":false,\"landingPage\":\"https://zadds.sg\",\"tagging\":[1,2,3],\"expandingDirection\":14,\"bdUrl\":\"\",\"format\":{\"code\":\"billboard\",\"name\":\"Billboard\",\"publisher\":\"default\",\"type\":\"standard\",\"width\":120,\"height\":600,\"expanded_width\":0,\"expanded_height\":0,\"collapsed_width\":0,\"collapsed_height\":0,\"aspratio\":3.76,\"expandable\":true,\"expand_first\":true}}",
  "bidResponseData": "{\"bids\":[{\"creative\":3,\"ext\":null,\"price\":\"72USD/1M\",\"priority\":1.0,\"spotIndex\":0},{\"creative\":2,\"ext\":null,\"price\":\"60USD/1M\",\"priority\":1.0,\"spotIndex\":1}]}",
  "biddingMainAccount": "859834ead1264843434cf6627ds43294d1",
  "impIndex": "1",
  "impressionId": "165",
  "rawWinPrice": "100USD/1M",
  "timestamp": "2015-Sep-04 04:44:24.49340",
  "userIds": "{\"prov\":\"aGtqaq2ikdta21kZ2ZpbGZu70mo\"}",
}
```

I do something like

```
    case class Bids(creative: Int, price: String, spotIndex: Int)

    case class BidResponseData(bids: Array[Bids])

        //
    case class UserId(prov: String, xchg: String)

    case class BidRequestString(id: String, isTest: Option[Boolean],
                                    url: String, userAgent: Option[String],
                                    exchange: Option[String], provider: Option[String],
                                    userIds: Option[UserId])

        //
   case class Format(width: Int, height: Int)

   case class BidResponseCreative(format: Format)

        //
   case class WinMessage(auctionId: String, bidRequestString: BidRequestString,
                              bidResponseCreative: BidResponseCreative, bidResponseData: BidResponseData,
                              biddingMainAccount: String, impIndex: String,
                              rawWinPrice: String, timestamp: String) 
  val jsonSerializer = {
        val m = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
        m.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        m.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        m
      }
  var message = jsonSerializer.readValue[WinMessage](eventMessage)
```

But I got error:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.knx.adx.storage.processor.BidRequestString]
```

So I do something like each element and parse it into json object.

```
    var message = jsonSerializer.readValue[Map[Any, Any]](eventMessage)
    message.foreach {
              case (k, v) => {
                if (k == "bidRequestString") {
                  val tempObj = jsonSerializer.readValue[BidRequestString](v.toString)
    }
    }
}
```

Is that the right way to do that? What can I do to make it better or parse faster? Right now it can parse only about 2k - 3k records/second.

Comment: How did you generate these Json objects ? They are invalid

Comment: @Dici JSON is from a Ad Exchange system so I need to deal with that.

Comment: Try google Gson parser, it handles this problem automatically && better than jackson.
https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid Json, your nested objects are not nested objects, they are mere strings containing a Json. They won't be parsed as Json and will remain strings.

Comment: Thanks but How to deal with that?

Comment: You won't be able to do any better than this, it has to be parsed anyway. BTW I don't see why it would be much slower than if you had a larger, valid Json

Comment: You mean parse json in my way look into every field then parse is not slower than If I have a valid json?

Comment: I think so. I don't see any reason why it would perform much worse. Using strings could actually even enable you to skip some nested fields without writing any specific code for this